# Apache Beam Dataflow job fails with "GetWork timed out, retrying"

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am able to run an Acache Beam job successfully using the `DirectRunner`, with the following arguments:

```
java -jar my-jar.jar --commonConfigFile=comJobConfig.yml   
--configFile=relJobConfig.yml 
--jobName=my-job   
--stagingLocation=gs://my-bucket/staging/   
--gcpTempLocation=gs://my-bucket/tmp/   
--tempLocation=gs://my-bucket/tmp/  
 --runner=DirectRunner 
--bucket=my-bucket   
--project=my-project 
--region=us-west1   
--subnetwork=my-subnetwork
--serviceAccount=my-svc-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com   
--usePublicIps=false   
--workerMachineType=e2-standard-2 
--maxNumWorkers=20 --numWorkers=2 
--autoscalingAlgorithm=THROUGHPUT_BASED
```

However, while trying to run on Google Dataflow (simply changing `--runner=DataflowRunner`) I receive the following message (`GetWork timed out, retrying`) in the workers.[image]

I have checked the logs generated by the Dataflow process and found

```
[2023-01-28 20:49:41,600] [main] INFO  org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.MonitoringUtil$LoggingHandler:91 2023-01-28T20:49:39.386Z: Autoscaling: Raised the number of workers to 2 so that the pipeline can catch up with its backlog and keep up with its input rate. 
[2023-01-28 20:50:26,911] [main] INFO  org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.MonitoringUtil$LoggingHandler:91 2023-01-28T20:50:26.779Z: Workers have started successfully.
```

and I see no indication that the workers have failed. Moreover I do not see any relevant logs which indicate that the process is working (in my case, reading from the appropriate Pub/Sub topic for notifications). Let me know if there is any further documentation on this log, as I have not been able to find any.

Comment: Do you see more log with the severity `debug` instead of `info` ? Do you see something in the Diagnostics tab ?

Comment: You can also try to check logs in Cloud Logging.

Comment: @MazlumTosun I see a few more logs with visibility `debug` but nothing that would indicate anything wrong.

Comment: Have you also checked in `Cloud Logging` ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun Yes.

Comment: Do you have any processing at all? Or no work is started? Might have to do with permissions/networking depending on your project https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions

Comment: @BrunoVolpato No work is started at all. I checked and the service account I'm using has Dataflow Admin, Dataflow Developer, and Dataflow Worker privileges. I have been able to run other jobs successfully with the same account. I don't think it's a permissions issue.

Comment: Got it. I would suggest opening a ticket with Google Support and provide a job id so this can be looked further. There might be some log indications but may be subtle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to include the `--enableStreamingEngine` flag. This solved my problem.